# Debugging ansible-playbook fails

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ansible

I am not very new to Python, fairly new to VSC (moved to MacOS recently) and very new to Ansible. I am trying to build a plugin to circumvent our weird jump host (long story and sad, so far). A very simple step would solve this, but, in trying to get where to put that step, I wanted to do a full debug of ansible-playbook python script and everything that comes with it.
I am on 1.29.1 Visual Studio Code, Ansible 2.7.0, Python 3.6.4 through anaconda.

What am I trying to do:

I have created a profile in launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Ansible playbook",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "args": [
        "--inventory=/full_path/inventory.ans",
        "/full_path/test-playbook.yml"
    ],
}...
```

that enables me to launch debug. I have tried without any breakpoints - it goes to the same point as it does when I run it in command line.
Short explanation about the arguments: .ans file is an Ansible repository explicitly specified (to override default config) and the other is the actual playbook. Contents of both do not play a role, I tried arguments for my other scripts - they are accepted...

I have added:

- Breakpoints at any point in the ansible-playbook file - while it stops there (paused on breakpoint in call stack window), I do not see any variables or anything in the left pane. Further, I have only options to pause, restart and stop debugging.
- If I add an option to break on start, I have exactly the same behaviour.
  I have downloaded PyCharm and did similar thing there and I have an option to go step by step, see variables and so on.

Any help/direction is appreciated.

If I try to debug my other Python scripts, it works as expected, I get yellow pointer and I can skip through steps. Main difference is that I do have a .py extension in my scripts and that I use very simple Object Oriented elements, not even close to what is in Ansible...

Comment: It might not work as I'm not sure how Ansible does things (e.g. what's a `.ans` file?). Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd .

Comment: @BrettCannon My company blocks access to github, but, I will do it tonight (UTC). It is strange that it just does not give anything...

Comment: @BrettCannon I have been using VSCode with ptvsd, since more than a year to debug ansible. It is not quite straight forward to setup debugging though. I will see if I can writeup a medium post over the weekend.

Comment: @noob_all_my_life You cannot debug the yaml playbooks directly. when invoking ansible though you can run it with `-vvvv` to get a verbose output. That would suffice in most cases.

Comment: @tux Thanks! I know about the playbook debugging. Interestingly, since you mentioned it, I have seen many display.debug lines, but, none print in the stdout, no matter how many 'v's I specify... About my problem: I am trying to debug (reverse engineer, frankly) the python code in ansible-playbook python script and modules it goes through, so I can make my changes - this stemmed from my need to use a jumphost which is not really ssh jumphost: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/_Ye7a12_DpE